# Impossible to install tensorflow with pip python

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, python-wheel

hello i have a problem for installing tensorflow in python with pip: i'm using pycharm with python 3.8 but when i want to install tensorflow i always get the same error:

```
pip3 install tensorflow
Collecting tensorflow
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

i tried a lot of way to install it but it always crash, thanks for the help and sorry for my english it's not my first language

Comment: Have you tried upgrading pip?
pip install --upgrade pip

Comment: yes i updated it i tried everything but don't work

Comment: According to tensorflow documentation Python 3.8 requires TensorFlow 2.2 or later and according to PyPI the latest release is 2.4.0, so "pip install tensorflow==2.4.0" should work.

Comment: You probably have 32bit Python installed instead of 64bit one.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+%5Btensorflow%5D+Could+not+find+a+version+that+satisfies+the+requirement+tensorflow+from+versions

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using *anaconda* to install tenserflow? If you dont have anaconda go to https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual#Downloads to install it.